# Nikkor 80-200mm f2.8D got stuck at af/mf lock button

Tags: nikon

I can not lock the button (at my finger) when I turn the ring to A mode. It locked at M mode normally. Is it serious problem, can I fix it by myself. Please give me some advises.
Thank for your comment.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lenses such as 70-200mm f/2.8 or 80-200mm f/2.8 are some of the most complex lenses made for mass production.¹

If you have to ask if you can fix it yourself the answer is almost certainly "No, you can not."

<sub>¹ You don't have to take my word for it. Check out some of Roger Cicala's lensrentals.com blog entries about teardowns of 70-200mm f/2.8 lenses: [Lens Teardowns and Comparisons of the Canon 70-200mm f2.8 IS II and III](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2018/08/lens-teardowns-and-comparisons-of-the-canon-70-200mm-f2-8-is-ii-and-iii/) and [Lens Teardown of the Complicated Sony FE 70-200mm f/2.8 GM OSS: Part I](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2017/02/lens-teardown-of-the-complicated-sony-fe-70-200mm-f2-8-gm-oss-part-1/) and [Completing the Teardown of the Sony FE 70-200 f/2.8 GM OSS: Part II](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2017/02/completing-the-teardown-of-the-sony-fe-70-200-f2-8-gm-oss-part-ii/)</sub>

Comment: Thank for your response. I know that it's hard to fix by myself. Because I didn't find the place where can fix this problem in my local area except Nikon center. This center in my country has very poor service. :((